# Spring Data Rest - Creating the parent and embedded object in one request

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a parent object that looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    private int pk;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Child> sentenceList;
}
```

And a child object that looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    private int pk;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

What I want to do is `POST` to the parent's repository to create the parent and also create the embedded children.  The POSTed JSON would look something like this:

```
{
    "title": "Parent"
    [
        {
            "title": "Child 1"
        },
        {
            "title": "Child 2"
        },
    ]
}
```

Is this possible with Spring Data REST?  I currently get an error stating that the parent PK can't be null.

Thanks for any help!